# Give object-based premissions in GCP IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

## Usecase :

I have a GCP setup with :

- multiple [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/) clusters
- multiple [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/) instances
- multiple [GCS buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/)

Basically, I'd like to give permissions to users with finer granularity than project-wide (ie user A can only access bucket B, but can access CloudSQL instances C and D)

## Possible solutions :

For GCS, this is [easy and documented](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions).

However, I couldn't find anything similar for the other two. The CloudSQL documentation even seems to say it is [not possible](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control) (`All permissions are applied to the project. You cannot apply different permissions based on the instance or other lower-level object.`)

## Workarounds explored :

- I tried creating [custom IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles). I was hoping that there would be some way to filter on objects the role is applied to, in a fashion similar to what AWS IAM [allows with its `Resource` filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_controlling.html).
  That's apparently not possible here.
- For GKE, I can give every user the `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Viewer` role (which basically just allows to list clusters and basic info about them, as well as logging on with `gcloud` cli tool), and then use the [Kubernetes RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) engine to give very fine-grained permissions. This works fine, but doesn't allow the user to use the Google web interface, which is extremely handy, especially for a beginner on k8s.
- Similarly, for CloudSQL, I can give the `Cloud SQL Client` role, and manage my users directly through the postgres access control system. This works fine, but my users are able to connect to other instances (they still need an account on these instances, of course). Moreover, operations such as restoring a backup cannot be allowed only on specific instances.

So, have I missed something obvious, or have anybody found some way to work around these limitations ?

Comment: Are you connecting to cloudsql via compute instances or appengine?  With appengine there is a way to restrict instance access to specific service roles.

Comment: I'm using it from compute engine indirectly (since k8s nodes are compute engine instances)

Answer (score 0):

For GKE, seems that the only option is using RBAC to give users fine grained permissions by [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) within a namespace or ClusterRoleBinding for cluster-wide permissions.

Regarding CloudSQL, currently not supports instance based permissions, but you can track any updates in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/68765990) for this feature request.